# rails/ruby "and return false" syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen this code in a rails tutorial I'm doing

```
def access_denied
  redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to continue" and return false
end
```

Before learning rails, I did a large amount of ruby research and none of the books I read covered this "and return false" syntax going on here. I can't find any mention of it in the rails syntax, is anyone able to provide a link or any explanation that would clear this up?

I don't understand the need for the "and" in here as I thought ruby would always return the last evaluated expression.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking *why* it would be used. In any case, if it's being used by a filter as described in my answer, be very wary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The **and** is there only for you to be able to write the **return false** at the same line as the previous statement.

It's equivalent of doing this:

```
redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to continue"
return false
```

it's not exactly the same because with the "and" it would only return false if the **redirect_to** method returns something that isn't **nil** or **false** but as it almost always returns something that is not **nil** nor **false** then the right side of the statement is always executed (and **false** is returned).

The **and** in Ruby is just an alias to **&&** and behaves exactly like it with only one difference, it has a lower precedence than all other pieces of the statement, so first it evaluates whatever is on it's left and then gets applied. Ruby also has the **or** which is the same as **||** but with a lower precedence in expressions.

Comment: If you ever want to add a return that always executes but you **aren't** confident that the first expression will always return non-false, you can also use a semicolon instead of `and`, like this: `do_something argument, argument; return false`

Answer (score 3):

`redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to continue"` is a normal expression in Ruby that does not return false (or nil, see the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/199dcaeade6c319a43b507dbc111cb15b78fa52b/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb)), so program execution continues (to check the second part after AND) and `return false` can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of construct used to be used with a filter, when filter return values were expected. The `false` would halt normal request processing.

So if a controller looked like this:

```
class FooController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :access_denied
  # etc.
end
```

None of the controller's actions would run; this method was likely designed to be called *from* a filter, like:

```
def check_access
  return access_denied unless current_user.has_access
end
```

These days filter return values are ignored.

It could be used as a normal method in an action to stop processing the action and return after the redirect, so no other logic/rendering/etc. is run inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on operators: [Under the "Defined?, And, Or, and Not" section](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html)

Using `and` is useful for chaining related operations together until one of them returns `nil` or `false`.  You can use it like you showed in your question or you can also use it to short-circuit the line of code.

```
# Short circuit example
blog = Blog.find_by_id(id) and blog.publish!
```

The blog only gets `.publish!` called on it if the `find_by_id` was successful.

In your example:

```
def access_denied
  redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to continue" and return false
end
```

They are just using it to write the code more compactly on one line.

However, it is also useful for a controller action where you may be rendering based on conditionals and you don't want to get Rails "multiple renders" warning:

```
def show
  if something
    render :partial => 'some_partial'
  end

  render :partial => 'some_other_partial'
end
```

Rails will give you a warning if `something` returns true since you have multiple render statements being evaluated in the action.  However, if you changed it to

```
if something
  render :partial => 'some_partial' and return
end
```

it would allow you to stop the action execution.